# What does "work" mean in football (soccer)?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "work" mean in football (soccer)?

GOAL! Everton pull one back! The home side keep pushing forward and work the ball over to Bolasie, who shoots from 20 yards out and manages to find the back of the net via the inside of the near post. Will that prove to be the start of an almighty comeback?

Answer (score 2):

This use of **work** isn't specific to football/soccer.  It's a slightly metaphorical usage, and there are a number of meanings of the verb *to work* that could apply here, but probably the most appropriate is

- [to get (oneself or an object) into or out of a condition or position by gradual stages](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/work)

So you could rephrase it as "they perform work to gradually get the ball over to Bolasie."